# How correctly deserialized my JSON object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a problem with JSON deserialization. I created a C# program and I used Json.NET.

The JSON object that I must deserialized is:

```
{
   "modifyDate": 1400648078000,
   "champions": [
      {
      "id": 143,
     "stats": {
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 7,
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalDamageTaken": 19377,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalMinionKills": 38,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 4,
        "totalDoubleKills": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 4862,
        "totalChampionKills": 4,
        "totalAssists": 17,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 4,
        "totalDamageDealt": 53289,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalSessionsLost": 0,
        "totalSessionsWon": 1,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 46696,
        "totalGoldEarned": 12787,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "maxNumDeaths": 7,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0
     }
  },
  {
     "id": 115,
     "stats": {
        "totalDeathsPerSession": 8,
        "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
        "totalDamageTaken": 18926,
        "totalQuadraKills": 0,
        "totalTripleKills": 0,
        "totalMinionKills": 219,
        "maxChampionsKilled": 4,
        "totalDoubleKills": 0,
        "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 8912,
        "totalChampionKills": 4,
        "totalAssists": 6,
        "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 4,
        "totalDamageDealt": 170050,
        "totalFirstBlood": 0,
        "totalSessionsLost": 1,
        "totalSessionsWon": 0,
        "totalMagicDamageDealt": 161137,
        "totalGoldEarned": 10950,
        "totalPentaKills": 0,
        "totalTurretsKilled": 0,
        "mostSpellsCast": 0,
        "maxNumDeaths": 8,
        "totalUnrealKills": 0
     }
   }, ...
```

It's an complex object.

My C# class which represents this object is:

```
class StatRankedJoueur
{

    private double modifyDate;
    public double ModifyDate
    {
        get { return modifyDate; }
        set { modifyDate = value; }
    }


    private int _summonerId;
    public int SummonerId
    {
        get { return _summonerId; }
        set { _summonerId = value; }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, double>> champions;
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, double>> Champions
    {
        get
        {
            return champions;
        }

        set
        {

            champions = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The deserialization:

```
StatRankedJoueur values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatRankedJoueur>(response);
```

But I've this problem when I compile:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.Dictiona>y`2[System.String,System.Double]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. >>{"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

I found this error is this website, but the solution was to change this line:

```
 StatRankedJoueur values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatRankedJoueur>(response);
```

by:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string,List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> >(json);
```

The problem is I don't have a "object" list is my JSON. So how can it be done?

Comment: Side note: avoid new here/thank you notes in post and tags in title. Showing problem information/code (as you did) is more than enough.

Comment: Note, that in your JSON example given above, "champions" is an **array** of objects, whereas in your C# class it is a **Dictionary**. Hence, the JSON deserializer rightfully complains about this mismatch. One approach would be to create *another class* that matches the JSON objects with "id" and "stats" properties, and declare your *Champions* property like `public List<AnotherClass> Champions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming JSON.NET knows to put an id into the int key field of your dictionary and stat properties as the inner dictionary keys... It may not be able to infer all that...

One of the class definitions that should work for your JSON is:
(I know it is camel cased instead of pascal casing... Change that using JSON attributes.)

```
public class Stats
{
    public int totalDeathsPerSession { get; set; }
    public int totalSessionsPlayed { get; set; }
    public int totalDamageTaken { get; set; }
    public int totalQuadraKills { get; set; }
    public int totalTripleKills { get; set; }
    public int totalMinionKills { get; set; }
    public int maxChampionsKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalDoubleKills { get; set; }
    public int totalPhysicalDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public int totalChampionKills { get; set; }
    public int totalAssists { get; set; }
    public int mostChampionKillsPerSession { get; set; }
    public int totalDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public int totalFirstBlood { get; set; }
    public int totalSessionsLost { get; set; }
    public int totalSessionsWon { get; set; }
    public int totalMagicDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public int totalGoldEarned { get; set; }
    public int totalPentaKills { get; set; }
    public int totalTurretsKilled { get; set; }
    public int mostSpellsCast { get; set; }
    public int maxNumDeaths { get; set; }
    public int totalUnrealKills { get; set; }
}

public class Champion
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public long modifyDate { get; set; }
    public List<Champion> champions { get; set; }
}
```

You can quickly generate C# classes for your JSON here: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Ty, 

But Should I change this line now : 
    JsonClass.StatRankedJoueur values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass.StatRankedJoueur>(reponse);

Because the summonerId has changed but the Champions List haven't changed

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON does not contain dictionaries, as a comment points out. Try this:

```
class StatRankedJoueur
{

    private double modifyDate;
    public double ModifyDate
    {
        get { return modifyDate; }
        set { modifyDate = value; }
    }


    private int _summonerId;
    public int SummonerId
    {
        get { return _summonerId; }
        set { _summonerId = value; }
    }

    private Champion[] champions;
    public Champion[] Champions
    {
        get
        {
            return champions;
        }

        set
        {

            champions = value;
        }
    }


}

public class Champion
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public int totalDeathsPerSession { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a few classes to represent the structure you are getting from your JSON.

```
public class StatRankedJoueur
{
    public double ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public int SummonerId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Champion> Champions { get; set; }
}

public class Champion
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public Stats stats { get; set;}
}

public class Stats
{
    public double totalDeathsPerSession { get; set; }
    public double totalSessionsPlayed { get; set; }
    public double totalDamageTaken { get; set; }
    public double totalQuadraKills { get; set; }
    public double totalTripleKills { get; set; },
    public double totalMinionKills { get; set; }
    public double maxChampionsKilled { get; set; }
    public double totalDoubleKills { get; set; }
    public double totalPhysicalDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public double totalChampionKills { get; set; }
    public double totalAssists { get; set; }
    public double mostChampionKillsPerSession { get; set; }
    public double totalDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public double totalFirstBlood { get; set; }
    public double totalSessionsLost { get; set; }
    public double totalSessionsWon { get; set; }
    public double totalMagicDamageDealt { get; set; }
    public double totalGoldEarned { get; set; }
    public double totalPentaKills { get; set; }
    public double totalTurretsKilled { get; set; }
    public double mostSpellsCast { get; set; }
    public double maxNumDeaths { get; set; }
    public double totalUnrealKills { get; set; }
}
```